# How to set a voltage sweep effectively in just one command? Python

Tags: python-3.x, pyvisa

I am trying to do a Current-Voltage sweep using PyVisa with a Keithley 6430 doing a complete loop of voltages going from zero to both positive and negative values: from 0 to +5, back to 0 and from 0 to -5 and back to 0 again.

To do that I basically used 4 different ranges and 4 different *for* loops like so:

```
 #Voltage values
 low = -5
 middle = 0
 high = 5
 step = 1

 voltage_range1 = np.arange(middle,high,step)
 voltage_range2 = np.arange(high,middle,-step)
 voltage_range3 = np.arange(middle,low,-step)
 voltage_range4 = np.arange(low,middle+1,step)

 data = [] 

 for voltage in voltage_range1:
 keithley.write('source:voltage:level {}'.format(voltage)) 
 data.append(keithley.query_ascii_values('read?'))

 for voltage in voltage_range2:
 keithley.write('source:voltage:level {}'.format(voltage)) 
 data.append(keithley.query_ascii_values('read?'))

 for voltage in voltage_range3:
 keithley.write('source:voltage:level {}'.format(voltage)) 
 data.append(keithley.query_ascii_values('read?'))

 for voltage in voltage_range4:
 keithley.write('source:voltage:level {}'.format(voltage)) 
 data.append(keithley.query_ascii_values('read?'))
```

The program works properly, but I couldn't find a more functional way to do this, like setting the whole process in just one *voltage_range* and avoid using 4 loops. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this could work:

```
voltage_range = np.array([]) # initialize

for array in (voltage_range1,
              voltage_range2,
              voltage_range3,
              voltage_range4)
    voltage_range = np.append(voltage_range, array)
```

And then you only have one loop iterating over `voltage_range`. You can replace the `voltage_rangeN` directly with the `np.arange()` too and basically you can make any sequence of values you'd like just by changing their position in the parenthesis.

So after modification your program looks like this:

```
# Voltage values
low = -5
middle = 0
high = 5
step = 1

data = [] 
voltage_range = np.array([]) # initialize

for array in (np.arange(middle,high,step),
              np.arange(high,middle,-step),
              np.arange(middle,low,-step),
              np.arange(low,middle+1,step)):
    voltage_range = np.append(voltage_range, array)

for voltage in voltage_range:
    keithley.write('source:voltage:level {}'.format(voltage)) 
    data.append(keithley.query_ascii_values('read?'))
```

You can merge the ranges 2 and 3 too:

```
for array in (np.arange(middle,high,step),
              np.arange(high,low-1,-step),
              np.arange(low,middle+1,step)):
```